# ModuleNotFoundError for model class in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I ran into the following **ModuleNotFoundError** error.

```
File "C:\django-project\CodingWithMitchBlog\demoproject\Blog\api\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from demoproject.Blog.api.views import api_detail_BlogPost_view
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoproject.Blog'
```

'Blog' is my appname.

[This is my project structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSaS7.png)

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to incorrect import statements used in the files. If the import statements has the projectname prefixed try removing it and run again.

For example change:

```
from demoproject.Blog.models import ModelClass
```

to

```
from Blog.models import ModelClass
```

in the urls.py file